# Retrieve the ViewModel of a view in prism

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, prism

There is a way to retrieve the ViewModel of a view using prism ? I have a list of Views and I need get the ViewModel of this Views in code,  I already linked the ViewModel to the view using this code line in the app.xaml.cs:

```
 ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<MyView, MyViewModel>();
```

But I didn't find a way to retrieve the ViewModel of a view using a prism or xamarin method.

Answer (score 5):

`var viewModel = Page.BindingContext as MyViewModel`